# LINQ: Substring Function From the Left

Tags: c#, linq, twitter, substring

I am trying to retrieve the values of 'Title' using the following codes:

```
private void GetTweets_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, ea) =>
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(ea.Result);
            XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";

            var items = from item in doc.Descendants(ns + "entry")
                select new Tweet()
                {
                    Title = item.Element(ns + "title").Value,

                    Image = new Uri((from XElement xe in item.Descendants(ns + "link")
                        where xe.Attribute("type").Value == "image/png"
                        select xe.Attribute("href").Value).First<string>()),
                };
            foreach (Tweet t in items)
            {
                _tweets.Add(t);
            }
        };

        client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/[username].atom?count=10"));
    }
```

I was able to retrieve a list of tweets, however, I want to remove the first 16 characters displayed by the 'Title' value.

Is there are way to use the sub string function here?
Thank you.

Comment: have you looked at Remove function of the string? it takes startindex and count parameters. did not it help?
here is the [ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk.aspx)

Comment: Have you tried using the substring function, as you yourself suggest?  If so, what happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `item.Element(ns + "title").Value` is a `string`, you should be able to use the [String.Substring(Int32) method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6.aspx).

```
Title = item.Element(ns + "title").Value.Substring(16),
```

Be aware that this will throw an exception if the length of the Title is less than 16 characters, so it would probably be best to test for that first.

```
Title = item.Element(ns + "title").Value.Length > 16 
        ? item.Element(ns + "title").Value.Substring(16) 
        : item.Element(ns + "title").Value,
```

Comment: That should be `...Value.Substring(16)`; the argument specifies the index of the first character to include in the returned substring.